# In R (dplyr), why does the order in which I use filter affect the output?

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm using the `flights` dataset in R and want to analyze which planes (identified by tailnumber) have the worst delays. I wanted to filter out flights that had fewer than 10 total flights, and considered two possible inputs:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(nycflights13)

flights %>% group_by(tailnum) %>% 
        filter(arr_delay>0) %>% 
        mutate(prop_delay = arr_delay/sum(arr_delay), count = n()) %>% 
        filter(count >10) %>% 
        arrange(desc(prop_delay)) %>% 
        select(year:day, tailnum, prop_delay, count)
```

This correctly does what I want. But I initially wrote this:

```
flights %>% group_by(tailnum) %>% 
        filter(arr_delay>0, n()>10) %>% 
        mutate(prop_delay = arr_delay/sum(arr_delay), count = n()) %>% 
        arrange(desc(prop_delay)) %>% 
        select(year:day, tailnum, prop_delay, count)
```

When I print the count variable, I still obtain tailnums with fewer than 10 flights.

In the first, I create a count variable and *then* filter it out after creating it, while in the second, I first filter out using n() and then create a count variable, but these are apparently different objects.

What am I really doing in the second one?

Comment: In the first case, you are only removing the rows where the 'arr_delay <= 0` and then you are creating the 'prop_delay, but in the second case, it is `&` condition i..e.  it will filter out  some groups entirely

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that in the first `filter`, it is only some rows are removed where the 'arr_delay' is less than or equal to 0 and this have no effect on the grouping column i.e. even if there is no group_by, it still does.

But, in the second case with `n()` as an `&` condition, the output of `n() > 10` returns a single TRUE/FALSE value which gets recycled to the entire group, resulting in either keep or discarding of the group

Using a small example

```
set.seed(24)
df1 <- data.frame(grp = rep(letters[1:3], c(2, 4, 5)), val = rnorm(11))

all.equal(df1 %>% 
              filter(val >0),
          df1 %>%
              group_by(grp) %>% 
              filter(val > 0), check.attributes = FALSE)
#[1] TRUE
```

Here, the `filter` on the 'val' have no effect whether it is grouped or not

whereas if we add a second case with `n()`

```
all.equal(df1 %>% group_by(grp) %>%
              filter(val >0),
           df1 %>%
               group_by(grp) %>% 
               filter(val > 0, n() > 2), check.attributes = FALSE)
#[1] "Component “grp”: Lengths (6, 5) differ (string compare on first 5)" "Component “grp”: 2 string mismatches"                              
#[3] "Component “val”: Numeric: lengths (6, 5) differ"
```

Answer (score 4):

In your first example, you first remove all records with `arr_delay <= 0` for each flight, and then keep all flights with `> 10` such records. So all remaining flights have at least `10` records with `arr_delay > 0`.

In your second example, you keep all records with `array_delay > 0` and `n() > 10` at the same time. If a flight has `n() > 10` records, but some are with `arr_delay <= 0`, those `arr_delay <= 0` records are removed. As a result, there may be less than `10` records left that meet the `array_delay > 0` requirement, which your `count()` captures.